# Onclick event in literal string in Preload for electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, preload

Well this is a thing i need help of some one who know how to get the element from a foreach that innerHTML into a table data that comes from a data base, i did it by this way but it is not the most optimize way, so i need help to do it by other way, i add an onclick event with javascript and the only thing i make by doing this is that the only button that works is the one on top of the table or the bottom button of the table.

This is the way i make it work:

```
//Preload
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "electron", {
printmovieonpreload: (results) => ipcRenderer.on("send-movie", (event, results) => {
            mylist.innerHTML = " "
            results.forEach(elements => {
                mylist.innerHTML += `<tr><td> ${elements.movie-name} </td>
                <td> ${elements.movie-duration} min </td><td><button id="btn" value="${elements.id-movie}" "/*this get all the onclick events of the page*/${onclick = deletefromtable}" type="button"  class="fas cli fa-trash-alt"></button></td>
                </tr>`;
            });
        })
});

async function deletefromtable(e) {
/* this is were i filter from id of the onclick event and how i reduce the value of the button to delete it*/
    if (e.srcElement.id == "btn") {
        const obj = {
            id: e.srcElement.value
        }
        await ipcRenderer.invoke('delete_movie', obj);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to not do this by string interpolation, but by letting the browser (in Electron's terms, Chromium) create elements of the wanted type and then setting their contents and appending them to the parent. This can (and should) be done like so:

```js
// inside your forEach function
var tr = document.createElement ("tr");
var td1 = document.createElement ("td");
var td2 = document.createElement ("td");
var td3 = document.createElement ("td");
var btn = document.createElement ("button");

td1.textContent = elements ["movie-name"];
td2.textContent = elements ["movie-duration"] + " min";

btn.id = "btn";
btn.classList.add ("fas", "cli", "fa-trash-alt");
btn.type = "button";
btn.value = elements ["id-movie"];
btn.onclick = delete_from_table;

td3.appendChild (btn);

tr.appendChild (td1);
tr.appendChild (td2);
tr.appendChild (td3);
myList.appendChild (tr);
```

For this to work, however, you must meet the following conditions:

1. The index strings for the `elements` array must be correct. I'm pretty sure that your code using string interpolation would throw errors, because `-` is an operator and cannot be used when referencing indices using the dot operator.
2. `delete_from_table` must be a function, not a string. Since it is not included in the code snippet you have posted, I cannot verify if my solution would work based off of that. However, it seems that you would rather like to bind `updatestatuscero` to the `onclick` event of the button. If so, simply replace `delete_from_table` with this function's name.

Just some more tips regarding general JavaScript:

1. Use braces wherever possible to make the code more intelligible. For example, you could have written your code like so:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "electron", {
        printmovieonpreload: (results) => {
            ipcRenderer.on("send-movie", (event, results) => {
                mylist.innerHTML = " "
                results.forEach(elements => {
                    mylist.innerHTML += `<tr><td> ${elements.movie-name} </td>
                        <td> ${elements.movie-duration} min </td><td><button id="btn" value="${elements.id-movie}" "/*this get all the onclick events of the page*/${onclick = delete_from_table}" type="button"  class="fas cli fa-trash-alt"></button></td>
                        </tr>`;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This way, the scope of the functions can be understood at first glance. Both you and any other person having to work with this code in the future will be very pleased if you keep it organised.

2. When using string interpolation, you can execute operations. This is why I stated that `-` is not valid in an index above. The reason for this is that any expression inside `${}` in an interpolated string will be evaluated and its return value will be included in the string. Thus,

```js
var testObject = {
    "test-prop": "def"
};
var stringA = `abc ${testObject.test-prop} ghi`; // Throws: ReferenceError, prop is not defined
var stringB = `abc ${testObject["test-prop"]} ghi`; // yields "abc def ghi"
```

What the expression inside `stringA` tries to do is to actually subtract `prop` from `testObject.test`, neither of which are defined.

3. Also, with string interpolation, you have executed an assignment (`${ onclick = delete_from_table}`) which caused the new variable `onclick` to be defined, the method to be (correctly) written to the HTML, but *not bound to the buttons' `onclick` event*! Instead, you could have done `onclick="${delete_from_table}"` just like you did with the `value` property.
4. *Don't **ever** insert HTML* by using `element.innerHTML`! Take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations) -- this method has some pretty unexpected implications. Better sanitise your HTML first, use `element.insertAdjacentHTML()` or simply create elements and add them to a parent element by using `element.appendChild()` as I showed you above. This way is also, in my opinion, but tastes differ, the cleanest way possible.

Comment: well it worked, thakyou to much, the buttons works perfect and the text print form the database in a rigth way, just one thing in your code you write textContents and its textContent, its just an observation, any way you help me to much thankyou and your tips helpme to understant some things.